# How to use time field in adding metrics data to the influx db?

Tags: python, python-2.7, metrics, influxdb, grafana

I am using the following lines of code to add metrics data in influxDB.

```
    def add_job_influx_db_metrics(tags_dict={}, values_dict={}, measurement='test'):
       influxdb_client = InfluxDB.get_connection()
       db_name = "mydb"
       influxdb_client.switch_database(database=db_name)
       current_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',time.localtime(time.time()))
       json_body = [
        {
          "measurement": measurement,
          "tags": tags_dict,
          "time": current_time,
          "fields": values_dict
         }
       ]
      response = influxdb_client.write_points(points=json_body)
      print "write_operation response", response
```

When I am integrating it with Grafana,data does not come up but when I am checking it on **127.0.0.1:8083** ,it shows the time is **1970-01-01T00:00:00Z**.Probably,it takes the start epoch time as default.
I wanted to take the time of the form **"2015-8-19T07:15:00Z"**.
How to take the time field in influxdb(python client) and what is timePrecision ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
 from datetime import datetime
 current_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

and use "time" like this in json_body-

```
"time": current_time
```

It works.

Answer (score 6):

You need UNIX timestamp, so it should be:

```
"time": int(time.time())
```

Edit:

Time with nanosecond time precision:

```
"time": int(time.time() * 1000000000)
```

Eventually, second precision can be used `"time": int(time.time())` and specified explicitly:

```
 write_points(points, time_precision='s')
```

Comment: Using an integer, as Jan Garaj suggests, avoids the string conversion needed when doing someting like `datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')`

Comment: this would not work as the time value is different int(time.time()) gives 1582753973 where the db will need 1582753928000000000

Comment: @PeterMoore you are right. So `int(time.time())` can be multiplied to get nanosecond time precision or `write_points(points, time_precision='s')` can be used to specify second time precision.

Comment: correct. you probably should edit your post so people don't get confused. oh and since i took this approach int(time.time() * 1000000000) it does preserve microsecond precision on time